# number of loops of binary search method

Tags: java, search, binary-search

hey i want to find the number of comparisons of a binary search i have made this method to count the number of comparisons. Yet, it always return -1 as it doesn't find the numsearch although the array contains the number.
this is my method.. count refer to the number of comparisons.

```
 public static int BinarySearch (int n, Integer[] ran) {
     int low = 0;
     int high = ran.length-1;
      int count = 0;
     int middle;
   while (low<=high) {

        count++;
        middle = (high - low)/2;
        if (ran[middle] == n)  {
            return count;
        }
        else if (ran[middle] > n)  {
            high = middle - 1;

        }
        else {
            low = middle + 1;

        }

    }


     return -1;          
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the last line from `return -1` to `return count`.

Comment: I tried it but it returns either 2 or continue in a loop which i have to stop it manually

Comment: The code itself is not really correct either.  Perhaps you should review your implementation.  I would change `middle = (high - low)/2;` to `middle = (high + low)/2;`

Comment: thank you bro, i have changed the code. Yet, it gives me either 5 or 4

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int BinarySearch(int n, Integer[] ran) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = ran.length - 1;
    int count = 0;
    while (high >= low) {
        count++;
        int middle = (low + high) / 2;
        if (ran[middle] == n) {
            return count;
        }
        if (ran[middle] < n) {
            low = middle + 1;
        }
        if (ran[middle] > n) {
            high = middle - 1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: thank you bro i think i cam up to a solution since the sorted array was in decending order so i had to change                                                         if (ran[middle] > n) {
            low = middle + 1;
        }
        if (ran[middle] < n) {
            high = middle - 1;